# Appending a single character suffix to the end of the image id, and before the file extension in a django template

Tags: django, templates, imgur

Iam using the imgur API for managing images on a website I am running. to acquire the thumbnail link you have to append a single character suffix to the end of the image id, before the file extension [as described here](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs). Is there a way to do this in the template language, or is it only possible solution as following?

```
            for image in images:
            url = image.link.rsplit('.', 1)
            image.thumbs = url[0] + 'm.' + url[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not split and join in `template(jinja)`. Better to go with the approach you have taken.

**Handle it in backend only**.

```
for image in images:
    url = image.link.rsplit('.', 1)
    image.thumbs = url[0] + 'm.' + url[1]
```